# Google colab change form parameters

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

Google colab form has a powerful feature called Forms, https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/forms.ipynb.

In that there is a dropdown option too, I want to modify the options of the drop-down list via code.

Is it possible to do so colab?

Example it should work in this manner:

```
n = input('Give a number : ')
arr = list(range(n))
dropdown = arr[0] #@param arr
```

I have tried the above code but it won't work simply because the param list is after `#`, hence it commented as python cant reach till there.

If not should I use Jupyter Widgets? Would they be efficient, fast, and most importantly **re-run cells on change?**